# find each link with jquery and a html string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to find every "a" tag in this HTML string

```
$(document).ready(function(data) {
    $.get('test.html',
        function(responseText){
        //find each a tag   
        }, "html"
    )
});
```

Why is that so damn difficult for me ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

getting all links and doing something with them:

```
$.get('test.html', function(responseText) {
    var $response = $(responseText);
    var $links = $response.find('a');
    $links.each(function(index, $link) {
        // go nuts
    });
});
```

for more, read the jQuery documentation - its pretty good!

Comment: cool, but how do I put the links a variable ? E.g var $links = $response.find('a');

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
$(responseText).find('a')
```

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure whether any of the code works if the `responseText` is a string.
You have to [HtmlEncode it using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219860/javascript-jquery-html-encoding/1219983#1219983) first and then find your `anchor` tag.

Example:

```
$("<div/>").html(responseText).find('a').each(function(idx, elm) {
    //here are your anchors
    //alert(elm.href);
});
```

Working Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/naveen/Tcp3t/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Create a jQuery object of the HTML and use [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/):

```
$(responseText).find('a');
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you get the right answer. But you could have faced a link in plain text without any reference tag to find it as I did.

I've found this jquery plugin that can indetify links inside a text and then create the  tags

Hope It will help somebody

[Jquery Linkify](http://soapbox.github.io/jQuery-linkify/)